# How to designate Atom to open Quartz window for plotting from R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, atom-editor

I'm using a terminal inside of Atom. When I try plotting in ggplot2 it opens a quartz window. How could I point the quartz window to open inside an atom tab instead?

I've looked at the quartz() function, but don't know how it specifies where it opens.

Any documentation or support would be greatly appreciated.